# Postdoc-led Lab Mutiny: Is this normal? What to do?

Tags: ethics, postdocs, tenure-track, lab-management, responsibilities

A new postdoc has written an email on behalf of all grad students (CCing us) accusing our professor of being irresponsible, saying we would all stop our experiments.

The postdoc has been helping PhD students with administrative tasks. My advisor does occasionally helps us with these things, but says that they are our responsibility. Recently, a student had an administrative problem, and this postdoc helped, but was unable to fix it. After, the postdoc complained to the lab that the professor is not doing their job and was hurting students in the process.Then the email.

A meeting is now scheduled. Before this the postdoc and my professor seemed friendly. My plan is join the meeting, and to stay neutral and silent.

I hope to start my own lab someday. Of course, this has me thinking about my own future. My questions: 1) How should the professor handle this? 2) Is this kind of situation common?

Comment: Interesting situation. You might want to specify field and region of the world, as academic culture can vary pretty widely.

Comment: Is this common?  No.  The rest of the question cannot be answered without knowing what the "administrative problem" was.

Comment: Certainly not normal.

Comment: Clearly state your neutrality. Don’t go to the meeting. Stay out of it!  If you go you could be lumped in with the dissenters, who are almost guaranteed to lose.